# How can I pass a pointer to a Perl function as a callback to a function with pointers as arguments in a Windows DLL?

Tags: windows, perl, api, callback

#### Perl Script

```
use Win32::API;  
use Win32::API::Callback;  

my $callback = Win32::API::Callback->new(Perl_Func,"PN", "N");  

 #Import 'C_Func' Function from dll  
my $test = Win32::API->new('dll_test','C_Func','KP','N');  
my $buf = pack('i*', (1, 2, 3));  
 #Calling the C dll Function 'C_Func' with arguments as pointer to 'Perl_Func' and integer array  
my $ret = $test->Call( $callback, $buf);  
print "final value=".$ret."\n";
```

#### Defining 'Perl_Func'

```
sub Perl_Func
{  

        ($a,$b)=@_;  
        print "entered into Perl Function"."\n";  
        print "int variable from dll=".$b."\n";  
        print "array first element from dll=".$a[0]."\n";  **#unable to access the value**  
        $res=$a[0]+$a[1]+$a[2]; **# unable to access the values here** 
        return $res;  
}
```

#### C Dll "dll_test"

```
int __stdcall C_Func( int (*PerlExpFunc)( int *, int ), int *d)  
{  

        int res,c[3]; 
        c[0]=d[0]; c[1]=d[1]; c[2]=d[2];   
        res=PerlExpFunc(c,10);  
        return(res);  
}
```

So here Output looks like this

```
    entered into Perl Function  
    int variable from dll=10  
    array first element from dll=    
    final value=0
```

So the program is entering into 'Perl_Func' being called from the dll. But inside this function, it is unable to access the values in the array passed as a pointer (variable `c` in dll and `$a` in 'Perl_Func') from the dll. Therefore no value is being displayed for `$a[0]` and final value i.e. the summation of 1,2 and 3 is coming out to be zero. **I guess I am not extracting the values from pointer to array, passed from C section, correctly in the Perl section.** Please tell me the proper way to do that.

Comment: I give up. I tried wrapping the pointer in a struct, but that does not seem to work either. This maybe a good time to learn XS.

Comment: Yeah, but XS material on the net seems to be a huge one. Cannot read and implement it in the short run. Anyway thnx for your help and time.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [Win32::API](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Win32%3a%3aAPI) and [Win32::API::Callback](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Win32%3a%3aAPI%3a%3aCallback). For more help, you're going to need to give more information.

Here is the progress so far:

#### mydll.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

__declspec(dllexport)
int __cdecl C_Func(LONG (*PerlExpFunc)(PLONG, LONG), PLONG c) {
    int result;
    result = PerlExpFunc(c, 10);
    return result;
}
```

Compiled using:

```
C:\Temp> cl mydll.c /LD /Gd /W3
```

#### test.pl

```
use strict; use warnings;
use Win32::API;
use Win32::API::Callback;
use YAML;

my $C_Func = Win32::API->new('mydll', 'C_Func', 'KP', 'N', '_cdecl');

my $callback = Win32::API::Callback->new(sub {
        my ($x, $y) = @_;
        print Dump \@_;
        return 42;
    }, ['P', 'N'], 'N'
);

my $array = pack 'L*', 0x41, 0x42, 0x43;

my $ret = $C_Func->Call($callback, $array);

print "final value= $ret\n";
```

The output from this is:

```
---
- A
- 10
final value= 42
```

Clearly, the callback is receiving the first element of the array passed to it. All three values do make it to `C_Func`. I am not sure what's up with the receiving end.

### Update:

Here is the issue (from `Win32-API-0.68/Callback/Callback.xs`). In `PerformCallback`, we have:

```
for(i=0; i < nparams; i++) {
    switch(params[i].t) {
    case T_STRUCTURE:
        itoa(i, ikey, 10);
        XPUSHs(sv_2mortal(*(hv_fetch((HV*)SvRV(self), ikey, strlen(ikey), 0))));
        break;
    case T_POINTER:
        XPUSHs(sv_2mortal(newSVpv((char *) params[i].p, 0)));
        break;
    case T_INTEGER:
    case T_NUMBER:
        XPUSHs(sv_2mortal(newSViv((int) params[i].l)));
        break;
    }
}
```

Looking at the case for `T_POINTER`, it's clear why we're getting only the first element of the array back (you can verify that by passing `0xdeadbeef` and observing `efbeadde` in the hex dump of the output).

Comment: Okk...But I cannot change the function in C i.e. cannnot change int * to plong. Anyway I will try the code you have written without changing  this. And secondly as you have shown in the declaration of PerformCallback, does it mean it is not possible then??

Comment: The `int *` to `PLONG` thing is a red-herring.

Comment: Okk man...Thanks for your help. I tried searching the net here and there, but could not find anything useful.